# libcamera-still hangs on pi 3B running bullseye lite (headless)

Tags: headless, libcamera

I'm struggling to transition to libcamera-still from raspistill on an older pi OS. I would just like to capture a single snapshot to file via a SSH connection.
I run

`libcamera-still -v -n --immediate -t 5000 -o test.jpg`

and I don't think anything is out of the ordinary in the messages (unless the 'No buffers available' messages are more ERROR than INFO?), but the software hangs indefinitely after "Camera started!". I can Ctrl-C out but no image is generated.
Am I missing something in the command line arguments?

```
[0:03:09.616368762] [898]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:738 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 2592x1944-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 2592x1944-pGAA
Camera streams configured
Buffers allocated and mapped
Still capture setup complete
Requests created
[0:03:09.683512290] [903]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: Saturation = 1.000000
[0:03:09.683651598] [903]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: Contrast = 1.000000
[0:03:09.683700916] [903]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: Brightness = 0.000000
[0:03:09.683742317] [903]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: AwbMode = 0
[0:03:09.683781480] [903]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: Sharpness = 1.000000
[0:03:09.683822726] [903]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: ExposureValue = 0.000000
[0:03:09.688557541] [903]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: AeExposureMode = 0
[0:03:09.688637064] [903]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: FrameDurationLimits = [ 100, 1000000000 ]
[0:03:09.688688986] [903]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: AeMeteringMode = 0
[0:03:09.688729555] [903]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: NoiseReductionMode = 2
[0:03:09.690618575] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for Unicam Image
[0:03:09.690727314] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for Unicam Image
[0:03:09.690803972] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for Unicam Image
[0:03:09.690934740] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for Unicam Image
[0:03:09.691056446] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for Unicam Image
[0:03:09.691377193] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for ISP Output0
[0:03:09.691457706] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for ISP Output0
[0:03:09.691532073] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for ISP Output0
[0:03:09.691631750] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for ISP Output0
[0:03:09.691856883] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for ISP Output0
[0:03:09.691926511] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for ISP Output0
[0:03:09.691999524] [898]  INFO RPISTREAM rpi_stream.cpp:133 No buffers available for ISP Output0
Camera started!
```

Comment: Is your OS fully updated? Have you tried increasing GPU memory?

Comment: Others with similar https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/issues/144

Comment: @CoderMike Yes the OS is fully up to date and I did increase GPU memory. Those similar posts are actual buffer problems ('Failed to allocate buffers'...). Since I get to the 'Camera started' bit, I think this is something else.